# Laravel 8: Before editing a user I first want to check his role if he is an Admin I do a redirect::back otherwise I let him edit

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F8Ep.jpg)

En Laravel 8.

Comment: You should not share images you should share your code. Please read code of conduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may work for you

```
public function edit($id){
   // other codes and logics 

   if($userRole === 'Admin'){
       // let him edit
    }
   else {
         // redirect back
     }
```

Note : make sure $userRole is a string not array. if its a array  specify its array index like $userRole[0] == 'Admin'

Answer (score 0):

Use  \Auth::user()->role to get role type and then if else

```
public function edit($id){
   // other codes and logics 

   if(\Auth::user()->role === 'Admin'){
       // let him edit
    }
   else {
         // redirect back
     }
```